# Por que o meu switch não gera os resultados corretos?

Tags: php, get, condição, switch

Estou usando uma condição e um switch para determinar alguns valores para algumas variáveis, mas não estou obtendo os resultados esperados.

Quando o link `<a href="index.php?post=myFile"></a>` é clicado, eu espero executar o primeiro `case` no switch, mas as variáveis ​​desejadas não são sobrescritas.

Este é o meu código que está no meu arquivo chamado index.php.

```
$titulo = '';
$keywords = '';
$descricao = '';
$post = empty($_GET['post']) ? '' : $_GET['post'];
$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? '' : $_GET['p'];

if ($post != '' || ($post == '' && $pagina != '')) {
    switch ($pagina):
    case 'myFile':
        $titulo = 'esta variável não muda o valor para esse arquivo';
        $keywords = 'esta variável não muda o valor para esse arquivo';
        $descricao = 'esta variável não muda o valor para esse arquivo';
        break;
    case 'home':
        $titulo = 'Página Inicial';
        break;
    case 'ultimasnoticias':
        $titulo = 'Ultimas Noticias';
        break;
    case 'contato':
        $titulo = 'Contato';
        break;
    case 'privacidade':
        $titulo = 'Privacidade';
        break;
    default:
        $titulo = 'Home';
        $pagina = 'home';
    endswitch;
} else {
    $titulo = 'Post';
}
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    if (empty($post)) {
    require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php';
    } else {
        require_once 'posts/' . $post . '.php';
    }
    ?>

<footer>Rodapé</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Meus resultados atuais são:

```
$_GET["post"] = "myFile";
$_GET["p"] = NULL;
$titulo = "Home";
$keywords = "";
$descricao = "";
$pagina = "home";
```

Meus resultados desejados são:

```
$_GET["post"] = "myFile";
$titulo = 'esta variável não muda o valor para esse arquivo';
$keywords = 'esta variável não muda o valor para esse arquivo';
$descricao = 'esta variável não muda o valor para esse arquivo';
$pagina = "home";
```

Por que não consigo atualizar o valor das variáveis ​​usando a primeira instrução do `case`? Resumindo, os valores do meu `case` não sofrem alteração somente para os arquivos que estão em um sub-diretório

Esse é o código que eu uso para os meus outros links, que estão no meu diretório principal:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="?p=home">Início</a></li>
     <li><a href="?p=ultimasnoticias">Últimas Notícias</a>
     <li><a href="?p=contato">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Obs: Eu não tenho certeza se a imagem abaixo vai ajudar em algo, mas por via das duvidas eu coloquei:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está funcionando sim: https://ideone.com/6WiYsS

Comment: @Maniero Eu estou fazendo algo de errado e não consegui descobri o que é. Olha, quando eu altero o link de `<a href="index.php?post=myFile"></a>` para `?p=myFile` sim o `case` altera o valor das variáveis. Mas não abre o arquivo dentro da `body` tag, sendo que ele está em um sub-diretório.

Comment: Então a pergunta é sobre outra coisa que não está descrito na pergunta? E não temos como saber o que ocorre com as informações postadas?

Comment: @Maniero Não, é exatamente o que eu falei na pergunta, os valores do `case` so são alterados para os arquivos do diretório principal.

Comment: E eu acabei de mostrar que na forma que você apresentou isso não é verdade. Só é se tem algo faltando ou escrito errado.

Comment: @Maniero Eu tentei rodar o meu script no site ideone como você havia feito. Mas apareceu um monte de erro. https://ideone.com/Mk9MnO Se o `case` realmente está funcionando, então o que eu estou fazendo de errado, ou como descubro?

Comment: @Maniero Eu vi que no seu link para o ideone você colocou essas duas linhas `$_GET["post"] = "myFile";` e `$_GET["p"] = "myFile";`, eu coloquei essas linhas no meu script, e realmente o `case` está funcionando. Então talvez o problema seja a querystring que estou usando? `index.php?post=myFile`

Comment: È o que eu falei, não tem como sabermos porque a pergunta não tem informação suficiente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82625/discussion-between-sabrina-and-maniero).